# Unable to locate package libsdl1.2-dev

Tags: sdl

I'm having issues trying to install sdl to run some applications. I used a string given by the FAQ of the app I was trying to run, but this is the result.

```
devlin@DiningRoomHP:~$ sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libsdl1.2-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libsdl1.2-dev'
```

Anyone able to help with this?

Answer (score 0):

First update :

```
 sudo apt-get update
```

Second: check which sdl versions are available:

```
sudo apt-cache search libsdl
```

In my ubuntu versions (wheezey, stretch,tara )  I see libsdl1.2-dev, libsdl2-dev are available.

Answer (score 0):

This error is often caused by not updating the latest info

Try

```
sudo apt update
```

then check the spelling again

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2-dev libsdl-image1.2-dev libsdl-mixer1.2-dev libsdl-ttf2.0-dev libpulse-dev libxt-dev
```

And I compiled my file that uses SDL_ttf and SDL_gfx this way:

```
gcc main.c -lm -I/usr/include/SDL -lSDL -lSDL_ttf -lSDL_gfx
```

`-lm`  is to include math library.
`-I/usr/include/SDL` to include header files of SDL.
`-lSDL -lSDL_ttf -lSDL_gfx` some of the libraries I used from SDL in my project.

Note: `main.c` should be repalced with `<yourfilename>.c`

Answer (score -1):

Try downloading the .deb from [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/libsdl1.2-dev/1.2.15-5ubuntu2) and installing it using

```
sudo dpkg -i [package].deb
```